# Google SQL Instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-sql, google-cloud-billing

I took Google cloud SQL instance to evaluate SQL instance. I created one database and after my  trail expire, my sql instance is also suspended though I have upgraded my account. Is there any way to recover my database.

Best Regards,
Mazhar

Comment: Who long did you wait before upgrading your account?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking over the documentation as it depends on the resource and how long it took you to upgrade your account. If its been longer then 30 days, reaching out to support would be your best option but it's no guarantee they can recover it.

[End of Trail](https://cloud.google.com/free/docs/gcp-free-tier#end)

> Any data you stored in Compute Engine is marked for deletion and might
> be lost. Learn more about data deletion on Google Cloud.
>
> Your Cloud Billing account enters a 30-day grace period, during which
> you can recover resources and data you stored in any Google Cloud
> services during the trial period.

[Deletion Timeline](https://cloud.google.com/security/deletion#deletion_timeline)

> Google Cloud Platform commits to delete Customer Data within a maximum
> period of about six months (180 days). This commitment incorporates
> the stages of Google’s deletion pipeline described above, including:
>
> Stage 2 - Once the deletion request is made, data is typically marked
> for deletion immediately and our goal is to perform this step within a
> maximum period of 24 hours. After the data is marked for deletion, an
> internal recovery period of up to 30 days may apply depending on the
> service or deletion request.